# Understanding random 2D directional vector generation 

Tags: c#, xna

I'm new to C# and XNA. I'm trying to build a simple game and I'm not sure how the Vector2 is working when it's used in directions. I got line of code to produce a random direction, but why is two numbers a two places? Is it X and Y at both or the first one only X and the second Y? Or is it about angles? Could it be a number above 100?

```
direction = new Vector2(Game1.rnd.Next(-100, 100), Game1.rnd.Next(-100, 100));
direction.Normalize();
```

Comment: Please note that that that method of generating a random direction will be non-uniform favouring diagonal directions (because the starting area is a square), and will throw an exception if the source vector happens to be zero (as Dervall mentions; 1-in-40000 chance in your code). Here is a better way that generates a direction by starting with a random angle: `var angle = random.NextDouble() * Math.PI; var direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angle), (float)Math.Sin(angle));`. Note the use of `NextDouble` rather than `Next`,for generating floating-point rather than integer numbers.

Comment: I know this is an old-ass comment, I'll go for it anyway :) Assuming `random.NextDouble()` generates a value between 0 and 1, won't multiplying this with `Math.PI` this just generate an arc? I'd assume multiplying with `Math.TwoPi` (or equivalent) would generate an entire circle? Please correct me if I've gotten this backwards (and again, sorry for commenting on such an old question/comment) :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `Random.Next` that takes two arguments, the range of the random function. The constructor to the `Vector2` takes only two parameters.

A 2D-vector is composed of two magnitudes, one along the X axis and one along the Y axis. What your code is doing is generating a random vector that points in a random direction. Then to use this as a directional vector it is normalizing it, which causes the length to be set to 1.

The numbers in this case are arbitrary, since it calls `Normalize`. You could use any number, as long as the ranges for both X and Y axis are equal the function will behave the same way.

Note that this method of vector generation will fail if both X and Y happens to be 0 at the same time. This might seem remote, but could happen.

Comment: Hmmm, now I got it, the Random.Next(-100,100) is the limit so a number between -100 and 100 can be produced? But I'm still a little confused about directions. Is this right: if X is -1 a sprite moves to the left and if Y is -1 the sprite moves to the left in a down pointing angle?

Comment: You are right about the ranges. Regarding directions, that depends. It is different based on how the coordinate system is set up. For screen space it is typically +x to the right an +y goes down. Easiest way to find out is to test it yourself.